# Statistics - regression, calculating variance

Tags: statistics, regression, least-squares

I have this problem:

Consider the regression model $y=ax^3+\epsilon$, therefore $y_k=ax_k^3+\epsilon_k$, where $e_k \approx N(0,\sigma^2)$ for all $k=1,2,...,n$.

a) Find the estimation of $\hat{a}$.
b) Find $E(y_k)$ and $var(y_k)$.
c) Prove that the estimation $\hat{a}$ is unbiased and $var(\hat{a})=\sigma^2 \frac{\sum x_k^3}{(\sum x_k^6)^2}$.

I think I managed to derive that $\hat{a}=\frac{\sum y_k}{\sum x_k^3}$...

Then I think that $E(y_k)=E(ax_k^3+\epsilon_k)=a.E(x_k^3)+E(\epsilon_k)=a.\frac{\sum x_k^3}{n}=\overline{y}$ and

$E(\hat{a})=\frac{E(\sum y_k)}{\sum x_k^3} = \frac{\sum y_k}{\sum x_k^3}=\hat{a}$.

But I'm not able to calculate the variances. I don't really think I know what I do. How do I do it please?

Comment: If you could do this for the model $y=ax+\epsilon$, then you could use that result when replacing all the $x_k$ by $x_k^3$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a.$$ S(\alpha) = \sum (y_k - \alpha x_k^3)^2$$ 
$$s'(\alpha ) = -2 \sum y_kx_k^3 + 2\alpha \sum x_k^6 = 0 $$
$$\hat{\alpha} = \frac{\sum y_k x_k^3}{\sum x_k^6} $$
$$
s''(\hat{\alpha}) = 2 \sum x_k^6
 >0$$
b. $$\mathbb{E} \hat{\alpha} = \frac{ \sum x_k^3 \mathbb{E} y_k}{\sum x_k^6} = \frac{ \sum x_k^3 \alpha x_k^3}{\sum x_k^6}  = \alpha. 
 $$
c.
$$
\operatorname{Var}( \hat{\alpha} ) = 
\frac{ \sum x_k^6 \operatorname{Var} ( y_k) }{(\sum x_k^6 )^2}
=
\frac{ \sum x_k^6 \operatorname{Var} (\alpha x_k + e_k) }{(\sum x_k^6 )^2}=
\frac{ \sum x_k^6 \operatorname{Var} (e_k) }{(\sum x_k^6 )^2}
 =  \frac{ \sigma^2\sum x_k^6 }{(\sum x_k^6 )^2}  = \frac{ \sigma^2 }{\sum x_k^6 } 
$$

Comment: Thank you. But I don't understand why $\text{Var}(y_k)=\sigma^2$. Could you explain please?

Comment: Sure. I added more steps